# Breezejs ComplexType not executing a custom initializer function

Tags: javascript, breeze, single-page-application

I have recently updated to Breezejs 1.4.2 and it appears that there is an issue with running a custom initializer.  My app registers the ctor and initializer correctly (i believe) with Breeze but when i retrieve a record from the entityframework backed webapi the initialiser is not being executed.  From the source of a checkin at [github](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/commit/d120dd29366f328782f1c33592f1cbe95312acae#L4R7684) it appears that the initialiser code has been commented out with a comment that the initialiser would be executed from another piece of code.  Any ideas how I might be able to fix this?  I will probably downgrade to 1.4.1 as it was working.  I will remove the commented out section it see if it works, but was wondering if there are other people out there experience the same thing?

**C#**

```
public class ForecastItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Result CurrentYear { get; set; }
    /* extra detail removed */
}


public class Result 
{
    public int? Actual { get; set; }
    public int? Estimate { get; set; }

}
```

**Javascript**

```
    function extendResult(metadataStore) {
        var ctor = function () { };

        var initialiser = function (entity) {
            entity.useEstimate = ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    return entity.actual() === -1 ? true : false;
                },
                deferEvaluation: true
            });
            return entity;
        };
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Result', ctor, initialiser);
    }
```

**EDIT**
I have uncommented out the code from the breeze.debug.js and it is now working.

ComplexType proto obejct

```
proto._createInstanceCore = function (parent, parentProperty ) {
    var aCtor = this.getCtor();
    var instance = new aCtor();
    new ComplexAspect(instance, parent, parentProperty);
    // TODO: don't think that this is needed anymore - createInstance call will do this 
    //if (parent) {
    //    this._initializeInstance(instance);
    //}
    return instance;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was a bug and has been fixed. The fix will be available in Breeze 1.4.3 or is available now from the Breeze Git repository. ... and thanks for finding it. :)